# Partial migration of ASP.NET code from synchronous to async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm working on migrating a fairly large chunk of code in ASP.NET that is currently synchronous and moving it to async/await. Most recommendations I've seen say to migrate all the way down the stack, so basically a shotgun approach with all the changes at once.

In order to reduce risk, I'd like to limit to scope of how much code is changing at one time, but this means that I need to call asynchronous code from synchronous methods in order to avoid code duplication.

I did some searching and found Stephen Cleary's Nito.AsyncEx NuGet package which has an AsyncContext.Run method which would enable this type of wrapping of async code.

Below is a sample of how I am thinking of doing the migration. The legacy code would call GetContent, which is synchronous, and is now just a wrapper for the GetContentAsync method. This gives me the flexibility of calling the synchronous method from legacy code that I'm not ready to change, but at the same time allowing me to use the async code wherever I choose to.

My question is, does this seem like a viable approach? Are there any drawbacks or potential performance issues to the synchronous wrapper method? How have others tackled the challenge of migrating a large code base to async?

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncMigration
{
    public class ContentManager
    {
        public string GetContent(string url)
        {
            return AsyncContext.Run(() => GetContentAsync(url));
        }

        public async Task<string> GetContentAsync(string url)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What AsyncContext does is to queue all calls, and execute them sequentially.  In essence.

You will hurt your performance further, because AsyncContext takes an extra thread to execute your async code, while blocking the current thread.  When called. you synchronous method will take a thread from the thread pool of the web-server.  This synchronous method will block on AsyncContext.Run, making its thread unavailable to process new calls.  In turn, AsyncContext will take another thread from the thread pool to get the job done.

In other words, with AsyncContext you waste double the threads than using pure synchronous calls only.